# Windows Phone Dev 8 change HyperlinkButton Image (NO SILVERLIGHT)

Tags: c#, windows, image, windows-phone-8, hyperlink

I'm making an Application where I change my HyperlinkButton image but it doesn't go.

```
var brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Pics/Test/1/1_10.png", UriKind.Relative));
MainButton.Background = brush;
```

I put this code in the click event method but the Debugger goes after the second Line to this code:

```
    #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

Comment: change ImageBrush to Image?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be getting an exception because of an invalid URI. Take a look at URI schemes here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx

Also, the image should be added as Content.